# Replacing characters in a String in Scala

Tags: string, scala, dictionary, functional-programming

I am trying to create a method to convert characters within a String, specifically converting all '0' to ' '. This is the code that I am using:

```
def removeZeros(s: String) = {
    val charArray = s.toCharArray
    charArray.map( c => if(c == '0') ' ')
    new String(charArray)
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do it? This syntax is not valid:

```
def removeZeros(s: String) = 
  new String(s.toCharArray.map( c => if(c == '0') ' '))
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can map strings directly:

```
def removeZero(s: String) = s.map(c => if(c == '0') ' ' else c)
```

alternatively you could use `replace`:

```
s.replace('0', ' ')
```

Comment: Do you know how to to replace double quote character? "

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre - Replace it with what? Something like `s.replace('"', ' ')` should work.

Answer (score 29):

Very simple:

```
scala> "FooN00b".filterNot(_ == '0')
res0: String = FooNb
```

To replace some characters with others:

```
scala> "FooN00b" map { case '0' => 'o'  case 'N' => 'D'  case c => c }
res1: String = FooDoob
```

To replace one character with some arbitrary number of characters:

```
scala> "FooN00b" flatMap { case '0' => "oOo"  case 'N' => ""  case c => s"$c" }
res2: String = FoooOooOob
```

Comment: I understood the question to be literally removing the zeros. If you want to replace them with another single character, `map` works.

Answer (score 1):

According to  Ignacio Alorre, if you want to replace others chars into string:

```
def replaceChars (str: String) = str.map(c => if (c == '0') ' ' else if (c =='T') '_' else if (c=='-') '_' else if(c=='Z') '.' else c)

val charReplaced = replaceChars("N000TZ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * how to replace a empty character in string
 */
val name = "Jeeta"
val afterReplace = name.replace("" + 'a', "")
```

Answer (score 1):

The go-to way to do it is to use `s.replace('0', ' ')`

Just for training purposes you might use tail-recursion to achieve that as well.

```
def replace(s: String): String = {
  def go(chars: List[Char], acc: List[Char]): List[Char] = chars match {
    case Nil => acc.reverse
    case '0' :: xs => go(xs, ' ' :: acc)
    case x :: xs => go(xs, x :: acc)
  }

  go(s.toCharArray.toList, Nil).mkString
}

replace("01230123") // " 123 123"
```

and more generally:

```
def replace(s: String, find: Char, replacement: Char): String = {
  def go(chars: List[Char], acc: List[Char]): List[Char] = chars match {
    case Nil => acc.reverse
    case `find` :: xs => go(xs, replacement :: acc)
    case x :: xs => go(xs, x :: acc)
  }

  go(s.toCharArray.toList, Nil).mkString
}

replace("01230123", '0', ' ') // " 123 123"
```